# Remove files not containing a specific string

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I want to find the files  not containing a specific string (in a directory and its sub-directories) and remove those files. How I can do this?

Comment: @SivaCharan yeah... from existence :)

Comment: By remove I mean: delete

Answer (score 17):

The following will work:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null grep -Z -L 'my string' | xargs --null rm
```

This will firstly use find to print the names of all the files in the current directory and any subdirectories. These names are printed with a null terminator rather than the usual newline separator (try piping the output to `od -c` to see the effect of the `-print0` argument.

Then the `--null` parameter to `xargs` tells it to accept null-terminated inputs. `xargs` will then call `grep` on a list of filenames.

The `-Z` argument to `grep` works like the `-print0` argument to `find`, so grep will print out its results null-terminated (which is why the final call to `xargs` needs a `--null` option too). The `-L` argument to `grep` causes `grep` to print the filenames of those files on its command line (that `xargs` has added) which **don't** match the regular expression:

> my string

If you want simple matching without regular expression magic then add the `-F` option. If you want more powerful regular expressions then give a `-E` argument. It's a good habit to use single quotes rather than double quotes as this protects you against any shell magic being applied to the string (such as variable substitution)

Finally you call `xargs` again to get rid of all the files that you've found with the previous calls.

The problem with calling `grep` directly from the `find` command with the `-exec` argument is that `grep` then gets invoked once per file rather than once for a whole batch of files as `xargs` does. This is **much** faster if you have lots of files. Also don't be tempted to do stuff like:

```
rm $(some command that produces lots of filenames)
```

It's always better to pass it to `xargs` as this knows the maximum command-line limits and will call `rm` multiple times each time with as many arguments as it can.

Note that this solution would have been simpler without the need to cope with files containing white space and new lines.

Alternatively

```
grep -r -L -Z 'my string' . | xargs --null rm
```

will work too (and is shorter). The `-r` argument to `grep` causes it to read all files in the directory and recursively descend into any subdirectories). Use the `find ...` approach if you want to do some other tests on the files as well (such as age or permissions).

Note that any of the single letter arguments, with a single dash introducer, can be grouped together (for instance as `-rLZ`). But note also that `find` does not use the same conventions and has multi-letter arguments introduced with a single dash. This is for historical reasons and hasn't ever been fixed because it would have broken too many scripts.

Comment: Any way if we want to check a list of string like `grep -r -L -Z 'Astring' OR 'Bstring' OR 'Cstring' * | xargs --null rm` ?

Comment: You can use the egrep form of grep and then search for alternative strings like so: egrep ... 'Astring|Bstring|Cstring' ...

Comment: @user1394 What problem are you seeing?

Comment: `xargs: illegal option -- -`

Comment: @user1394 Can you show me what you're typing and the response you see

Comment: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null grep -Z -L 'pattern' | xargs --null rm


xargs: illegal option -- -
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]`

Comment: @user1394 What Operating system are you using

Comment: @Nick I'm using MacOS

Comment: @user1394 Commiserations! The toolset is different on MacOS - based on the BSD tools that Apple got for free when they based MacOS on that free but not copyleft OS. The comment above is based on the much richer GNU toolset that you get on Linux. You could try replacing the '-print0' arg to find with -print and removing the --null args from the two xargs. It'll be slightly less safe but will work in 99.9% of cases

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** This is how you **SHOULD NOT** do this! Reason is given [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk%3a_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-). Thanks to @ormaaj for pointing it out!

```
find . -type f | grep -v "exclude string" | xargs rm
```

Note: `grep` pattern will match against full file path from current directory (see `find . -type f` output)

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but FYI, it was probably due to [xargs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)

Comment: @ormaaj OMG! I used to use this quite often (xx;) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: this command is really awesome, it work fast and perfectly

Comment: TLDR; why is it that you should NOT use it?

Answer (score 5):

GNU grep and bash.

```
grep -rLZ "$str" . | while IFS= read -rd '' x; do rm "$x"; done
```

Use a `find` solution if portability is needed. This is slightly faster.

Comment: @Peter.O Strange I can't reproduce that. It appears if using `-r` it has no choice but to default to files unless `-` is given explicitly. Still, `.` is probably a good idea. Added it.

Comment: I've already deleted my original comment when  you added the `.`,  as you've no doubt seen, but I am a bit puzzled too, because 'man grep' shows `[FILE ...]` for the last option... but that is definitely what happens here (ie. waiting for input, without `.`); *GNU grep 2.5.4*

Comment: The default "." for grep -r was added in grep 2.11, pretty recent. And GNU don't respect man pages that much.

Comment: Ah, `2.12` here. `2.5.4` is the oldest available in my repo.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is

```
find . -type f '!' -exec grep -q "my string" {} \; -exec echo rm {} \;
```

You can remove the `echo` if the output of this preview looks correct.

The equivalent with `-delete` is

`find . -type f '!' -exec grep -q "user_id" {} \; -delete`

but then you don't get the nice preview option.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can see the rm command is running in the command line, but nothing is deleted after finishing the command. All the files do exist yet. I manually checked the files, and saw that some of them doesn't contain the string...

Comment: There seems to be some confusion on whether you meant to identify files without a certain string in their *name* or in their *contents*. This answer (with -v instead of -q) would be looking at the filenames. My answer looks at the contents.

Comment: @Hakim the command echoes instead of actually deleting. It's a good practice to __try__ before deleting. If the listed files are correct, remove the word `echo`.

Comment: That would find files containing given string ... not `NOT containing`. for that reason I give `-1`, because that answer could ruin someones life. I am flagging as well.

Comment: @Flash - really, how hard is it to add `!` to `find`'s arguments to invert the sense?  It's not like anyone would blindly copy an answer without trying to understand what does.  And `echo rm` hardly ruins anyone's life.

Comment: @TobySpeight ask Ian, not me. If someone asks for something, he is expecting an answer. Not totally opposite. And not hard to remove that echo when it seems to work fine. You are wrong with your crusade, man.

Comment: @Flash - no crusade; and it was easier just to correct the answer with a small edit ;-)

Answer (score 4):

To remove files not containing a specific string:

**Bash:**

To use them, enable the extglob shell option as follows:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And just remove all files that don't have the string "fix":

```
rm !(*fix*)
```

If you want to don't delete all the files that don't have the names "fix" and "class":

```
rm !(*fix*|*class*)
```

**Zsh:**

To use them, enable the extended glob zsh shell option as follows:

```
setopt extended_glob
```

Remove all files that don't have the string, in this example "fix":

```
rm -- ^*fix*
```

If you want to don't delete all the files that don't have the names "fix" and "class":

```
rm -- ^(*fix*|*class*)
```

It's possible to use it for extensions, you only need to change the regex: (*.zip) , (*.doc), etc.

Here are the sources:

https://www.tecmint.com/delete-all-files-in-directory-except-one-few-file-extensions/

https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190819/1296122.html

Comment: This is by far the easiest answer. I love globbing syntax, and will probably add the `shopt` command to my `bashrc`... is there any downside?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways to approach this. Here's one: find and grep to generate a list of files with no match, and then xargs rm them.

```
find yourdir -type f -exec grep -F -L 'yourstring' '{}' + | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

This assumes GNU tools (grep -L and xargs -d are non-portable) and of course no filenames with newlines in them. It has the advantage of not running grep and rm once per file, so it'll be reasonably fast. I recommend testing it with "echo" in place of "rm" just to make sure it picks the right files before you unleash the destruction.

Comment: This one isn't doing [xargs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) right either. If using xargs, `-0` is the only way.

Comment: -d '\n' is a good enough way until you get a filename with a newline in it. It disables most of the xargs stupidity, like -0 does. Nice to learn about grep -Z though.

Comment: a filename with a newline in it? how about the guy with a cat on keyboard? He can't type long command like this! ar ya, that's crazy. but you can find that on youtube.

Comment: yep, it's fine if there's only sane filenames.

Comment: Ok. This works fine to me. I removed spaces in filenames and checked this script. Thank you Alan.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (although not as fast). The top solution didn't work in my case because the string I needed to use in place of 'my string' has special characters.

```
find -type f ! -name "*my string*" -exec rm {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, you can remove the -f if you're okay with deleting directories.

```
myString="keepThis"
for x in `find  ./`
    do if [[ -f $x && ! $x =~ $myString ]]
        then rm $x
    fi
done
```